# Removal of points from plot

Tags: r, points

I'm trying to plot 4 lines from 4 different y-axis variables vs. the same x-axis variable on one graph. I am currently using:

```
plot(df$x1, df$y,
     lines(smooth.spline(df$x1, df$y), col="red"),
     main="Decrease over 10 years",
     ylim = c(0, 10),
     xlim = c(0,10),
     xlab="Years",
     ylab="Percentage",
     pch="",
     las = 1
)

points(df$x2, df$y,
       lines(smooth.spline(df$x2, df$y), col="blue")
points(df$x3, df$y,
       lines(smooth.spline(df$x3, df$y), col="green")
points(df$x4, df$y,
       lines(smooth.spline(df$x4, df$y), col="black")
```

However, when I plot this I obtain the 4 desired curves, but also "o" points along the x-axis. Is there a way to remove these points (they don't refer to the data)? I've tried using the pch="" option, but this does not remove the points.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Why are you putting "lines" inside a `plot` call?  If all you want is lines, then just do `plot(x,y, type='l')` .  However, I can guarantee that any points plotted are part of the data; you've forced the zxis limits so some data may well be "on" the axis.  Since you didn't provide a reproducible sample of your data, I can't help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

I am using lines(smooth.splines(...)) as I have artificially created data according to a given relationship between the y values and the four xi values. However, when I use type="l", this overcomes the plotting of points along the x-axis (these points do not refer to any data points, as I have no data where y=0 (or relatively close to zero).

As for how my data is different from that generated by MrFlick, I would still need to suppress the plotted points("o").

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem with

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(
    x1=sort(rnorm(25, 5, 2)),
    x2=sort(rnorm(25, 5, 2)),
    x3=sort(rnorm(25, 5, 2)),
    x4=sort(rnorm(25, 5, 2))
)
df<-transform(df, y=x1*2-1+rnorm(25))

plot(df$x1, df$y, lines(smooth.spline(df$x1, df$y), col="red"))
points(df$x2, df$y, lines(smooth.spline(df$x2, df$y), col="blue"))
points(df$x3, df$y, lines(smooth.spline(df$x3, df$y), col="green"))
points(df$x4, df$y, lines(smooth.spline(df$x4, df$y), col="black"))
```

But i didn't see anything unusual on the plot. Can you explain how your data is different than the sample I generated?

[image: sample plot]